# AppAuth-Android синхронное обновление токена внутри AuthInterceptor

Tags: android, ios

Добрый день *оверфлоуфцы*! Работаем над преоктом, на днях, столкнулись с недочетом в библиотеке [AppAuth-Android](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android). Отсутствует синхронный запрос на обновление токенов.

После каждого запроса к данным, выполняется проверка: не испортился ли токен? В случае если это так - должно его обновить, и повторить запрос за данными. Библиотека реализует обновление токена только *асинхронно*. Но в логике этого приложения, и класса, запрос должен быть синхронным. Сейчас, реализация обновления выполнена в лоб, т.е. формируется запрос, и отправляет за получение токена. Увы, почему-то запрос не работает. Ругается на неверный запрос, хотя поля сверены и перепробованы раз 10. Мне право надоело с ним разбираться, и пытаться починить этот костыль. Скажите, как можно реализовать логику синхронного обновления с помощью этой либы? Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с этой проблемой.

Код перехватчика **AuthInterceptorBase**:

```
public class AuthInterceptorBase implements Interceptor{
    protected Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "AuthInterceptorBase";

    public AuthInterceptorBase(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        if (response.code() == 401){
            Log.i(TAG, "Refreshing...");
            Request.Builder newRequestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder();
            boolean isSuccess = refreshToken(context);

            if (!isSuccess){
                Log.i(TAG, "Refreshing failed!");
                return new Response.Builder().request(originalRequest)
                        .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_2)
                        .code(401)
                        .message("Refreshing token failed")
                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.aditro.hateoas+json; charset=utf-8")
                        .body(response.body()) //body is necessary for Response otherwise Runtime exception will be thrown
                        .build();
            } else {
                String newAccessToken = SharedPrefsUtils.getAccessToken(context);
                newRequestBuilder.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + newAccessToken);
                return chain.proceed(newRequestBuilder.build());
            }
        } else {
            return response;
        }
    }

    private static synchronized boolean refreshToken(Context context) {
        try {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            String oldToken = SharedPrefsUtils.getAccessToken(context);
            String oldRefreshToken = AuthStateHelper.getRefreshToken(context);

            if (StringFormatter.isStringNullOrEmpty(oldToken) || StringFormatter.isStringNullOrEmpty(oldRefreshToken)){
                Log.e(TAG, "no oldToken or refreshToken found: " + oldToken);
                return false;
            }

            RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("grant_type", "refresh_token")
                    .add("scope", "openid graph-api offline_access")
                    .add("client_id", "native-app-client")
                    .add("refresh_token", oldRefreshToken)
                    .add("token_type", "Bearer")
                    .build();

            final Request request = new Request
                    .Builder()
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + oldToken)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .url(APIConfig.TOKEN_ENDPOINT)
                    .post(formBody)
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            Log.i(TAG, "Response: " + response.body());

            if (response.code() != 200)
                return false;

            try{
                String body = response.body().string();
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(body);
                AuthStateHelper.saveAuthState(
                        context,
                        object.getString("access_token"),
                        object.getString("id_token"),
                        object.getString("refresh_token"));

                Log.i(TAG, "New access token: " + object.getString("access_token"));
                Log.i(TAG, "New refresh token: " + object.getString("refresh_token"));
                return true;
            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Бибилиотека используется и в ISO, и в Android версии. Проект *outsource*. В IOS такая же проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге, все-таки проще оказалось исправить запрос. Помог ресурс https://jwt.io/ - распарсив токены, увидели неверные поля. Изменили их - все заработало.